# Forcing a preference for an overload in class definition?

Tags: c#, overloading, optional-parameters, overload-resolution

I have a generic class. It has 2 constructors. Those are widely used in my organization's codebase.

```
class MyClass<T> {
  MyClass() { ... }
  MyClass(T defaultValue) { ... }
}
```

I would like to add some functionality but keep backward-compatible. So I would like to introduce a new boolean optional parameter to each constructor:

```
class MyClass<T> {
  MyClass(bool someFlag = false) { ... }
  MyClass(T defaultValue, bool someFlag = false) { ... }
}
```

However, I already have a heap of usages out there in which T is boolean and a default value is passed:

```
class Usage {
  MyClass<bool> Booly = new MyClass<bool>(false);
}
```

Now, according to the laws of overload preference - the compiler is tying all such constructor usages to the overload accepting `someFlag`, since typed methods "know better". While making perfect sense in most cases, this is obviously breaking my backward-compatibility.

My question is simple: Is there a language feature available for me to *override* the default laws of overload preference, and define the old generic overload as the preferred one, so that I don't have to change all such usages?

Of course, a drawback of this design is that whenever I would want to call the first overload (with only the `someFlag` parameter) - I would have to specify a named parameter as per C# 4 specifications.

Suggestions for other designs are also welcome, but please try to answer my question first :).

Comment: _Is there a language feature available for me to override the default laws of overload preference_ - No.

Comment: @jrummell thanks, I was suspecting so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can have an `Initialize()` type method that you can call from each constructor, your best bet is to have three constructors:

```
MyClass() { Initialize(null, false); }
MyClass(T default, bool someFlag = false) { Initialize(default, someFlag); }
MyClass(bool someFlag)
{
   if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))  Initialize(someFlag, false);
   else Initialize(null, someFlag);
}

private Initialize(T default, bool someFlag)
{ 
   // Do whatever
}
```

Comment: Was hoping to avoid type checking but I guess that's the most readable answer out there. Still curious if anyone comes up with something cleaner..

Answer (score 1):

In general? No.

A specific... "workaround"... which might be acceptable in your case? Make the optional parameter a `bool?`, not a `bool`.

`new MyClass<bool>(false)` will call your `defaultValue` overload.

`new MyClass<bool>(someFlag: false)` will call the other overload.

That said, if you have any existing `new MyClass<bool?>(false)` calls, this will change *them* over instead.

You can overcome *this* by creating an class specifically for making your flags not be bools:

```
public struct FakeBool
{
    private readonly bool val;
    private FakeBool(bool val) { this.val = val; }
    public static implicit operator bool(FakeBool f) { return f.val; }
    public static implicit operator FakeBool(bool f) { return new FakeBool(f); }
}

public MyClass(FakeBool someFlag = default(FakeBool)) { ... }
public MyClass(T defaultValue, FakeBool someFlag = default(FakeBool)) { ... }

var b2 = new MyClass<bool>(true);            // calls two-argument constructor
var b1 = new MyClass<bool>(someFlag: true); // calls one-argument constructor
```

but this is getting silly. (Also, I can't figure out how to get a default value of *true* - any ideas, anyone?)

Comment: Hehe ok thumbs up for creativity but this is indeed getting silly :). As much as I wanted to avoid type checking, I guess I'd have to go with @Bobson's answer. Thanks!